# How to get the json corresponding to the dropdown when I activate the change event?

Tags: angular

How can I get the json completely? for example, if I select the second option, I would like to obtain:

```
{"name":"goku", "ki":23232, "planet":"vegita"}
```

this is my code:

```
 <select  [(ngModel)]="dropdown" (change)="fn_change(item)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of aData" value="item.name">{{item.name}} 
   </option>
 </select>

aData=[
 {"name":"goku", "ki":23232, "planet":"vegita"},
 {"name":"vegeta", "ki":11, "planet":"vegita"},
 {"name":"krillin", "ki":5565, "planet":"earth"}        
]

 fn_change(item){
  alert(item);
  console.log(item);
}
```

how can I do it?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6crza?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngValue` instead of `value`
**Try these code**

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="dropdown" (change)="fn_change(dropdown)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of aData" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: cool! One last question, how do I select an element by default, to prevent this option from being blank?

Comment: Just set the default value to dropdown model

Comment: yes, need to set just default value to dropdown model.